# Update (REST API) a Google document with api key

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-docs-api

I can't figure out what public data means in Google Docs API guides.
Reading the Google Docs API guide [authorizing section](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/authorizing), we find that for public data the OAuth 2.0 is not necessary, then I tried using `patchupdate` to update a document which is shared to edit for anyone with the link, and I could not get it to work because the API returns an authentication error.
So the questions are, what is API key for and what does Google mean with public data?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you refer to the [«*If the request doesn't require authorization (such as a request for public data), then the application must provide either the API key or an OAuth 2.0 token, or both*»](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/authorizing) part. It says that you should use either an API key or an OAuth 2.0 token (or both), whatever is more convenient for your project. In this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) you can learn more about how to communicate with Google APIs using OAuth 2.0. Meanwhile in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) you can see the approach used with API keys. Please don't hesitate to ask me to clarify myself.